# defining the path of an image dynamically

Tags: php

I've created a simple fiunction, not sure whether I should be using a switch/case for the evaluation, but here goes. It should take the value of the field and determine which image its should use and then retuen the path of the image to the img tag. I've got my img tag below calling the function, any advice on what Im doing wrong?.

Many thanks

```
function imgtype ($parameter) {
   if ($paramater) === "T") {$imgsrc = 'images/onetick.gif'; return $imgsrc;}
   elseif ($parameter === "TT") {$imgsrc = 'images/twotick.gif'; return $imgsrc;}
   elseif ($parameter === "X") {$imgsrc = 'images/cross.gif'; return $imgsrc;}
}
```

This is the tag that calls the function

```
<img width="29" height="19" src="<?php imgtype($myRecord->getField('fieldvalue')); ?>">
```

Comment: You are not using the return value. `<?php echo imgtype(...)`. Also, since `imgtype` does not return a *type* but a *relative URL* it should be renamed.

Comment: you need to either echo result in function or echo result

Comment: I've now changed the fucntion name to imgURL - makes much more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the result:

```
<img width="29" height="19" src="<?php echo imgtype($myRecord->getField('fieldvalue')); ?>">
```

You are doing it good using `if` `else` statements. It is suppose to be slightly  faster than `switch`, more yet if you use `===` rather than `==`, as you are doing.

[Performance info.](http://www.phpbench.com/)

Answer (score 0):

uses echo to call the function:

```
echo '<img width="29" height="19" src="'.imgtype($myRecord->getField('fieldvalue')).'">';
```

Or add it in function

```
function imgtype ($parameter) {
   if ($paramater) === "T") $imgsrc = 'images/onetick.gif'; 
   elseif ($parameter === "TT") $imgsrc = 'images/twotick.gif';
   elseif ($parameter === "X") $imgsrc = 'images/cross.gif';

return '<img width="29" height="19" src="'.$imgsrc.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` the return value like this:

```
echo imgtype($myRecord->getField('fieldvalue'));
```

or you can `echo` in your function:

```
function imgtype ($parameter) {
   if ($paramater) === "T") {$imgsrc = 'images/onetick.gif'; echo $imgsrc;}
   elseif ($parameter === "TT") {$imgsrc = 'images/twotick.gif'; echo $imgsrc;}
   elseif ($parameter === "X") {$imgsrc = 'images/cross.gif'; echo $imgsrc;}
}
```